# Trying to authenticate remotely

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, identityserver4, openid-connect

I've created an OpenID Connect identity provider using ASP.NET Core and IdentityServer4 and published it to Azure.  I can authenticate with the provider using an MVC app that's hosted on my Azure VM, however, when I try to run the same app and access my provider from my local PC I run in to a 404 error.  My provider website partially displays and looking at the traffic in MS Edge, my client app is successfully authorized via the authorize endpoint.  CORS is also enabled for my client app with a record in ClientCorsOrigins.  Looking for any ideas on how to get past the 404 and to the login screen for my identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

Is your IdentityServer really available and reachable outside Azure?

Comment: Yes, I confirmed I can browse the discovery document.  After further research, it looked like my ClientRedirectUri wasn't correct and updating that got me past the 404.